# How do I configure phpPgAdmin (hosted on Heroku) to only display my database?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, phppgadmin

There are hundreds of databases displayed on the Heroku Postgres (amazon hosted) shared environment. Using pgAdmin3, there is a filtering feature to remove the unneeded databases.
Is there a similar configuration option for phpPgAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

Simple config option I missed:

```
// Only show owned databases?
// Note: This will simply hide other databases in the list - this does
// not in any way prevent your users from seeing other database by
// other means. (e.g. Run 'SELECT * FROM pg_database' in the SQL area.)
$conf['owned_only'] = true;
```